# Route53 traffic routing based on user location with api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have an application that is in the `us-east-1` region with following

```
API gateway -> lambda -> dynamo DB
```

I wanted to have these resources in multiple regions (in `Mumbai and Europe) to decrease the latency.

What I did

- I have created `Global tables` for my data in dynamoDb
- Created 3 separate lambda functions in 3 regions
- Created 3 API gateway rest APIs in 3 regions

Now the question is

- How do I have just one subdomain (api.example.com) which can route the request to the appropriate API gateway endpoint based on user location that will definitely reduce the latency.

I created a custom domain in my API gateway like `us-east-1-api.example.com, ap-south-1-api.example.com, eu-central-1-api.example.com` and mapped my APIs.

Now in the `Route53`, I created an `A record` for `api.example.com` but I am not getting any API gateway resources to connect to. but when I try to have the same subdomain in route53 such as `us-east-1-api.example.com` then it shows me the `us-east-1` API gateway CloudFront resource.

but this would mean that I will have to create 3 different subdomains records which is not what I wanted.

I want to have a single subdomain that can route the traffic to the appropriate API gateway based on the user location.

I tried searching a lot but did not find what I was looking for. would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you use lambda@edge which leverages cloudfront

Comment: Not finding any online resources on how to create a CloudFront for lambda that can just return the JSON data. everywhere it's only to show an HTML page. would appreciate it if you can point me to any online resource for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would create `api.example.com` as [latency records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-latency.html).

In your case you would have three latency recordcs called `api.example.com`. Each of them would point to other A alias record in your HZ (`us-east-1-api.example.com`, `ap-south-1-api.example.com`, `eu-central-1-api.example.com`):

```
                             |-> us-east-1-api.example.com (ALIAS to API gateway in that region)
api.example.com (latency) -> |-> ap-south-1-api.example.com (ALIAS to API gateway in that region)
                             |-> eu-central-1-api.example.com (ALIAS to API gateway in that region)
```

Comment: Tried this, but when i add custom domain to API Gateway, it gives me a cloudfront URL. in route53 when I try to add the latency record, it asks me for cloudfront resource on selecting ALIAS to API gateway and it only show up when I enter the same domain `us-east-1-api.example.com` in rute53 instead of `api.example.com`

Comment: @Manojahirwar Your api must be regional.

Comment: My api is regional already. I have added screenshot here https://ibb.co/Lkfv0Y1
 and
 https://ibb.co/Wnq1G61 
I am not gettig what i am doing wrong @marcin

Comment: I got it. For regional apis too i need to create custom domain name in api gateway. Now i am able to get them to connect to route53. thanks for your help

Comment: Just one question. when i select `latency routing` in route53, it asks me to choose the region. what does this region mean? Is it the user who is making a request region? do i need to create ALIAS record for all the possible regions?

Comment: @Manojahirwar You choose region where your services are. You wrote that your app is in three regions, so you will create three latency regions of same name `api.example.com` (one for each region).